# while loop with foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

This is my while loop.

```
$getsongs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hth_songs WHERE album='$album'");
while($song = mysql_fetch_array($getsongs)){
?>
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" },

<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that I always need to have a "," at the end of my echo. but if its the last item i dont want the "," in the end.

I have looked it up and i need to do something like this, but I cant make it work, and dont know what to do with this.

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
   if ($i == 0) {
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" }, // first
   } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" } // last
   }
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" }, // …
$i++;
}
```

(im running this php snippet inside a < script> and thats why i need a "," in the end excpet the last item)

Any help will be much appriciated.

Comment: Try creating a string as you iterate through the while loop and then use rtrim after the while loop. That will get rid of ending comma (,) http://php.net/rtrim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've missed an 'else' in your code:

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
   if ($i == 0) {
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" }, // first
   } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" } // last
   }
   else
    { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" }, // …
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a comma-delineated string from values in an array is to use implode().

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Notice there is no trailing commas as the comma is the "glue" that pieces the values together.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a title too much. Try this:

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
   $i++;
   if ($i == $len) {
      { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" } // last
   } else {
      { title:"<?php echo $song[title]; ?>" }, // others
   }     
}
```

Comment: So do i make my array like this?
$array = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hth_songs WHERE album='$album'"));

Comment: I don't know, that's another question. I just saw the while-appending problem and that is the same in every language (when you don't use special features like @FatAdama gave).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense, where is $song set?   And why the extra curly braces inside the if blocks?

Assuming you can adjust to your situation:

```
$string = '';
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $string .= $item['song'] . ',';
}
echo rtrim($string, ',');
```

Comment: The $song is only set in my while loop because i cant figure out how to set it to retrieve the $song data in the foreach loop.